# Keep function from affecting certain parts of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am creating a program which will sort people's names into different tables(table1, table2, table3, table4) which are represented by arrays and it will add any preferences that people would like to sit by into the same table as them. I have a function, check(), which makes sure there are no duplicate names and that the tables' length does not exceed 6. The problem is the check() function moves the preferences out of the table they need to be in. Is there any way to keep this from happening? Thank you.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var table1 = [];
    var table2 = [];
    var table3 = [];
    var table4 = [];
    var names = [];
    var pref = [];

    function seat() {
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (pref != "") {
                if (pref == names[i]) {
                    var who = names[i];
                    function prandomize(min, max) {
                        var pr = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                        if (pr == 1) {
                            table1.push(names[i]);
                            table1.push(who);
                        } else if (pr == 2) {
                            table2.push(names[i]);
                            table2.push(who);
                        } else if (pr == 3) {
                            table3.push(names[i]);
                            table3.push(who);
                        } else if (pr == 4) {
                            table4.push(names[i]);
                            table4.push(who);
                        } else {
                            return "Error: Contact Source Code Author!!";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function randomize(min, max) {
                var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                if (r == 1) {
                    table1.push(names[i]);
                } else if (r == 2) {
                    table2.push(names[i]);
                } else if (r == 3) {
                    table3.push(names[i]);
                } else if (r == 4) {
                    table4.push(names[i]);
                } else {
                    return "Error: Contact Source Code Author!!";
                }
            }
            randomize(1, 4);
        };
        console.log(table1);
        console.log(table2);
        console.log(table3);
        console.log(table4);
        console.log("first call");
    };

    var htable1 = document.getElementById('t1');
    var htable11 = document.getElementById('t11');
    var htable111 = document.getElementById('t111');
    var htable1111 = document.getElementById('t1111');
    var htable11111 = document.getElementById('t11111');
    var htable111111 = document.getElementById('t111111');

    var htable2 = document.getElementById('t2');
    var htable22 = document.getElementById('t22');
    var htable222 = document.getElementById('t222');
    var htable2222 = document.getElementById('t2222');
    var htable22222 = document.getElementById('t22222');
    var htable222222 = document.getElementById('t222222');

    var htable3 = document.getElementById('t3');
    var htable33 = document.getElementById('t33');
    var htable333 = document.getElementById('t333');
    var htable3333 = document.getElementById('t3333');
    var htable33333 = document.getElementById('t33333');
    var htable333333 = document.getElementById('t333333');

    var htable4 = document.getElementById('t4');
    var htable44 = document.getElementById('t44');
    var htable444 = document.getElementById('t444');
    var htable4444 = document.getElementById('t4444');
    var htable44444 = document.getElementById('t44444');
    var htable444444 = document.getElementById('t444444');

    function check() {
        var stable1 = table1.slice().sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < table1.length - 1; i++) {
            if (stable1[i + 1] == stable1[i]) {
                table1.splice(i, 1);
                console.log("removed");
            }
        }
        if (table1.length > 6) {
            while (table1.length > 6) {
                var lastvalue = table1.pop();
                table2.push(lastvalue);
                console.log("moved to table2");
            }
        }
        if (table2.length > 6) {
            while (table2.length > 6) {
                var lastvalue2 = table2.pop();
                table3.push(lastvalue2);
                console.log("moved to table3");
            }
        }
        if (table3.length > 6) {
            while (table3.length > 6) {
                var lastvalue3 = table3.pop();
                table4.push(lastvalue3);
                console.log("moved to table4");
            }
        }
        if (table4.length > 6) {
            while (table4.length > 6) {
                var lastvalue4 = table4.pop();
                table1.push(lastvalue4);
                console.log("moved to table1");
            }
        }
    }

    function changeHTML() {
        htable1.innerHTML = table1[0];
        htable11.innerHTML = table1[1];
        htable111.innerHTML = table1[2];
        htable1111.innerHTML = table1[3];
        htable11111.innerHTML = table1[4];
        htable111111.innerHTML = table1[5];

        htable2.innerHTML = table2[0];
        htable22.innerHTML = table2[1];
        htable222.innerHTML = table2[2];
        htable2222.innerHTML = table2[3];
        htable22222.innerHTML = table2[4];
        htable222222.innerHTML = table2[5];

        htable3.innerHTML = table3[0];
        htable33.innerHTML = table3[1];
        htable333.innerHTML = table3[2];
        htable3333.innerHTML = table3[3];
        htable33333.innerHTML = table3[4];
        htable333333.innerHTML = table3[5];

        htable4.innerHTML = table4[0];
        htable44.innerHTML = table4[1];
        htable444.innerHTML = table4[2];
        htable4444.innerHTML = table4[3];
        htable44444.innerHTML = table4[4];
        htable444444.innerHTML = table4[5];
    }

    function namesdefine() {
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameone').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwo').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namethree').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefour').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefive').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namesix').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameseven').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameeight').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namenine').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameten').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameeleven').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwelve').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namethirteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefourteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namefifthteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namesixteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameseventeen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nameeighteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('namenineteen').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwenty').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentyone').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentytwo').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentythree').value);
        names.push(document.getElementById('nametwentyfour').value);
        console.log(names);
        var testvar = document.getElementById('nameone').value;
        console.log(testvar);
        console.log("Look here please");
    }

    function prefsdefine() {
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefone').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwo').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefthree').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preffour').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preffive').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefsix').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefseven').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefeight').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefnine').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preften').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefeleven').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwelve').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefthirteen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preffourteen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preffifthteen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefsixteen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefseventeen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefeightteen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('prefnineteen').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwenty').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwentyone').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwentytwo').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwentythree').value);
        pref.push(document.getElementById('preftwentyfour').value);

    }

    document.getElementById('sbm').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        namesdefine();
        prefsdefine();
        seat();
        check();
        check();
        check();
        changeHTML();
    });

    console.log(table1);
    console.log(table2);
    console.log(table3);
    console.log(table4);
    console.log("second call");
    console.log(pref);

});
```

Comment: Declaring functions inside loops and `if` statements is a bad idea and will be flagged as an error in "strict" mode (if not always, but some interpreters).

Comment: Just by the looks of this code i didn't like it.

Comment: Why do you do three `check()` calls in your `click` handler?

Comment: @rasmeister I did that as a way of ensuring that every table was under 6 because I couldn't find a way to loop the function until all tables were under 6.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you first focus on the data structures that you are using before you try to go too much further. The preferences handling is trickier than it seems at first because you could have person1 who wants to sit with person2, but person2 wants to sit beside person6. This creates a chain of preferences that is not trivial to handle.

Before you try to tackle that, I would suggest you try creating a single data structure (rather than four tables). This data structure might be an array of size 24 holding objects that looks something like this:

`{ name: 'xxx', preference: 'yyy', table: n }`

If you are not comfortable with objects, or arrays of objects, I would suggest that you focus your efforts on learning them since they are absolutely essential in JavaScript. Arrays are handy but, in practice, they tend to be for very simple lists or as containers to hold objects.

I could provide you code that will do what you want but I don't think that will help you in your learning curve. Take a stab at applying a different data structure and if you get stuck there, maybe post a new question on SO. There are plenty of people that want to help but you will need to do your homework to get assistance along the way.

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping. I think I will try to implement a data structure as you said.

Comment: It is much easier to set the table property to indicate the table they are at than to move entries from one array to another. Best of luck... and hopefully see more questions from you on SO soon!

Comment: Yes, I'm only seeing now how much easier this would have been had I used an object data structure in the first place. I'm almost done and hopefully all goes well.

Comment: Constantly refactoring your code with small improvements (or large) is a good thing.